# UBCD4Windows creates empty iso file

Tags: iso-image, ubcd

I've got a case of a laptop that goes round and round thru the famous BSOD. I cannot disable the automatic reboot in BIOS, F8 does not work either and booting into the Safe Mode results in another BSOD. I did some research and found [How To Disable Automatic Restart For BSOD If You Are Unable To Get Into Windows](http://www.technibble.com/how-to-disable-automatic-restart-for-bsod-if-you-are-unable-to-get-into-windows/) which uses UBCD4Win as a tool. I head to [How to Build the Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/howto.htm)  and closely follow the steps yet I get the following in the log file:

```
Running external program
C:\UBCD4Win\mkisofs.exe -iso-level 4 -volid "The Ultimate Boot CD for Windows" -b bootsect.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -hide bootsect.bin -hide boot.catalog -o "C:\UBCD4Win\test.iso" "C:\UBCD4Win\BartPE"
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
        1 file(s) moved.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Check for different Bootloaders:
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
C:\UBCD4Win\BartPE>"C:\UBCD4Win\temp\mkisofs.exe" -iso-level 4 -volid ""UBCD4Windows"" -A PEBUILDER/MKISOFS -sysid ""Win32"" -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -hide boot.catalog -allow-lowercase -R -U -sort C:\UBCD4Win\temp\pe_sort.txt -duplicates-once -b BOOTSECT.BIN -hide BOOTSECT.BIN -o "C:\UBCD4Win\test.iso" .   2>&1  | mtee /+ C:\UBCD4Win\autobuild.log 
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Incorrect function.
Building ISO image done
```

When I browse to the test.iso file I get file with 0 bytes and I cannot burn that.

I've tried running IMGburn and building iso with that but that did not work well. Can someone point to the rights direction to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Which OS has the bsod?

Comment: There are other rescue CDs/USBs that you can try. One of them (no idea how legal it is so not mentioning the name here) includes *Registry Editor PE* that should work just as well as the one in UBCD.

Comment: @Moab It is WinXP (SP unknown)

Comment: @Darius google search for a copy of Microsoft's ERD Commander 2005 v5.0 boot disc, has many good tools.

Comment: @Moab I've tried Hiren's BootCD and load the Mini Win XP but that does not see the drive hence I cannot change the reg key to disable autoreboot in case of crash. This is so annoying... I will try this ERD Commander and see what happens

Comment: What is even more annoying is that when the laptop boots from Ubuntu Live disk I can easily browse the local C drive yet when I boot Hiren''s BootCD Mini Win XP or even the MS ERD Commander I cannot access the C drive due to "there is not enough space on the disk" "error". Aghr

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with UBCD4Win.  I point it to my WinXP CDROM on hard drive with SP2 and it makes a 0kB ISO file.  Then I realised from http://www.ubcd4win.org/faq.htm#require that you have to run the program from Microsoft Windows XP.  You can't run it from Win7/8/10.  Fair enough.  The solution is to run WinXP on VirtualBox in order to create the UBCD ISO.